# template argument deduction of return type in function template

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following minimal example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

template<typename ContainerOut, typename X, typename Y, typename ContainerIn>
ContainerOut Map( const ContainerIn& xs, const std::function<Y( const X& )>& f )
{
    ContainerOut ys;
    std::transform( begin( xs ), end( xs ), std::inserter( ys, end( ys ) ), f );
    return ys;
}

struct Foo {
    Foo( int val ) : val_( val ) {}
    int val_;
};

std::set<int> FooValsToIntSet( const std::list<Foo>& foos )
{
    //Map<std::set<int>, Foo, int>
    return Map( foos, []( const Foo& foo )
    {
        return foo.val_;
    } );
}

int main()
{
    std::list<Foo> foos = { 1, 2, 2, 3 };
    std::set<int> vals = FooValsToIntSet( foos );
    for ( auto& v : vals )
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

The line

```
return Map( foos, []( const Foo& foo )
```

is not accepted by the compilers I [tested](http://ideone.com/QiAna9).

It works if I write out the template arguments explicitly instead:

```
return Map<std::set<int>, Foo, int>( foos, []( const Foo& foo )
```

But I do not understand why this is necessary. Is there a way to avoid this verbosity?

Comment: There are two different questions here really. One is the imputation of the return type, and the second is the issue of passing a lambda to where a `function<T>` is expected. Both are basically impossible as is, but workarounds are possible

Comment: C++ does **not** do top-down type propagation:  Figure out what type the usage requires from a sub-expression and use that info in understanding the type of the sub-expression.  Instead it does bottom-up: First figure out the type of a sub-expression, then try to fit that to the usage (with automatic casts possible in some cases).  If the type can't be figured out bottom-up, any type knowledge implied by the usage can't be applied.  Your `return` is a usage that implies a required type.  But the expression you are returning must have a known type before the usage is considered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the compiler has no way of deducing the `ContainerOut` type - the return type doesn't participate in type deduction. However, you could let the compiler deduce everything except the return type. Just as a side note, at least in this case, there is no reason to use `std::function` - it's just adding unnecessary overhead.

This would be better:

```
template<typename ContainerOut, typename ContainerIn, typename F>
ContainerOut Map( const ContainerIn& xs, F&& f )
{
    ContainerOut ys;
    std::transform( begin( xs ), end( xs ), std::inserter( ys, end( ys ) ), f );
    return ys;
}
```

and then you can call it as

```
return Map<std::set<int>>( foos, []( const Foo& foo )
{
    return foo.val_;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to *need* the actual template parameters inside `Map()`, so you can deduct the function object as a single parameter:

```
template<typename ContainerOut, typename ContainerIn, typename Function>
ContainerOut Map( const ContainerIn& xs, const Function& f )
{
    ...
}
```

This is also how STL algorithms taking a predicate do it.